# Purposeful selection and confounding

Tags: feature-selection, epidemiology, confounding

I conducted purposeful selection as outlined in Jewell's *Statistics for Epidemiology*. The log likelihood tests showed covariates, which I considered to be confounding though not significant in the modeling, as not significant when excluded. In the end, however, goodness of fit test was significant. When re-introduced the "confounding" covariates, goodness of fit was not significant. Unfortunately, I am unable to find much research in this subject as it is more so for the purpose of policy and program practice so a reference for which variables to hold is lacking.

Should I still keep covariates believed to be confounders regardless of the log likelihood test results?

Comment: Confounding need not stay a "belief". By definition, a confounding variable is associated with both the dependent variable and the main regressor of interest. Have you checked pairwise covariance/correlation between each candidate confounder and the dependent variable, and also between the former and the regressor of interest?

Comment: @Alecos Yes, one of the covariates of interest was highly correlated at >0.80. I've also found high correlation between covariates at >0.90, which I believe is due to the variables almost saying the same thing. I was basically handed a dataset to "explore". I've read in Gidden's 
Regression Methods in Biostatistics that such strong correlated relationships can remain in the model? When looking at the VIF, however, they multicollinearity is >8.0.

Comment: @Alecos I meant that the correlation between independent variables or should I also remove one of them as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES! Confounders should not be evaluated in terms of their "significance". The more important thing to consider is how their inclusion changes the exposure-outcome relationship.

However, even more important, potential counfounders should only be included after a thorough evaluation of the hypothetical mechanism connecting the exposure to the outcome, preferably using directed acyclic graphs.

Comment: Thanks, D L Dahly. Since recently finishing graduate school, I've only now started to understand the "differences" held among biostatisticians and epidemiologists. The purposeful selection method was taught by a biostatistician who swears by Hosmer-Lemeshow. I almost forgot the usefulness of DAGs, but I will revisit them.